# Why does apple encrypt the .ipa before compressing it?

Tags: ios, encryption, compression, app-store

As described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1795/_index.html), Apple encrypts the .ipa before compressing it, which likely makes the compression useless ([SO](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/19970/117551)) and your app much larger to download.

What are the reasons for this decision?

Comment: The encryption is required by the FairPlay DRM system; if the binaries weren't encrypted then you could potentially copy an ipa file from one device to another and use an app without purchasing it. When you purchase an app you are given a user key that is used to access the master key required to decrypt the binary.

Comment: But why don't the compress then encrypt?

Comment: Because then iOS would need to decrypt and uncompress the binary and store that uncompressed binary somewhere, which would increase the on-device storage required, slow launch times and leave an unencrypted version of the binary sitting on the file system. Other assets in the ipa are not encrypted and can be compressed. Device storage is limited and expensive. Increased network transfer time is a one-off impact vs permanently greater device storage used and decreased security

Comment: A few uninformed questions then: what is iOS keeping on disk? An uncompressed encrypted binary that is decrypted every time you launch the app? That sounds surprising and slow. But else we have an unencrypted file sitting somewhere right?

Increased network transfers also happen every time the app updates, so that's a lot.

Comment: Yes, an encrypted, uncompressed binary that is decrypted as it is loaded into memory.  Decryption is performed in hardware so it is pretty fast, but yes, there is some overhead.  That is why people who "swipe up" all their apps in the belief that they are improving the performance of their device are actually making it slower and using more battery.  Update network transfers are still only once per update.  Essentially this is the price of keeping the binary secure

Comment: I am sceptical about how much a compiled binary would compress anyway; There are probably much greater bandwidth savings from the app thinning that Apple performs on their side.

Answer (score 0):

### I can think of at least two reasons

1. The statement that the IPA is encrypted is wrong... Pages of the binary are encrypted, not the entire IPA.
2. The ZIP provides a storage format for a variety of elements most of which compress nicely.